# How to update field to push value to existing value in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, explode, implode

I want to update `questions` table `answerid` column with the comma separator, when users give the answer many times against one question.
This is `answers` table bellow:

```
id   questionid   answer
1        1         ans1 
2        1         ans2
3        1         ans3
```

And my `questions` table is:

```
id   userid   questions  answerid
1     100        q1         1
2     110        q2
3     1345       q3
```

After answering many times against one question then `questions` table should be like:

```
id   userid   questions  answerid
1     100        q1       1,2,3
2     110        q2
3     1345       q3
```

When user answering the question then I am saving this into my database like bellow:

```
public function saveAnswer(Request $request)
{
    $id = session()->get('did');
    $phone = session()->get('phone');
    $email = session()->get('email');
    if(empty($phone) || empty($email)){
        return redirect('donor-login');   
    }

    $answer = DB::table('answers')
                    ->insert([
                        'questionid' => $request->questionid,
                        'answer'     => $request->answer,
                        'created_by' => $id,
                        'updated_by' => $id,
                        'created_at' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
                    ]);
    if ($answer) {
        DB::table('questions')
                 ->where('id', $request->questionid)
                 ->update([
                    'answerid' => ????here is my problem
                 ]);
        return back()->with('success', 'Your answer successfully saved!');
    }

}
```

Comment: Simple use like this `->update([
                    'answerid' =>DB::raw('CONCAT(answerid,",2")')]);`

Comment: I am getting trouble to replace `2` with a variable in your query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update the answerid with current ids and concat with ,

```
DB::table('questions')->where('id', $request->questionid)->update(['answerid'=>DB::raw("CONCAT(answerid,',".$answer."')")]);
```